# forloop with ifelse, merge of two dataset

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, merge

I have two datasets.
A with two columns:
col1 with the number of the sampling station and col2 with the date.
B with:
col1 with the number of the sampling station, col2 with the date, col3 the age of the species that found and col4 with the temperature values

for example

```
A<- matrix(c(1,"2011-07-15",2,"2011-07-20",3,"2011-07-15",4,"2011-07-18",5,"2011-07-20"),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
B<-matrix(c(1,"2011-07-12",3, 21, 2,"2011-07-20",4, 20,2,"2011-07-18",2, 20,3,"2011-07-15",10, 21,3,"2011-07-13",8, 22,3,"2011-07-12",7, 19,4,"2011-07-12",9, 19,4,"2011-07-10",7, 21,5,"2011-07-20",8, 21),ncol=4,byrow=TRUE)


>A
   [,1] [,2]        
[1,] "1"  "2011-07-15"
[2,] "2"  "2011-07-20"
[3,] "3"  "2011-07-15"
[4,] "4"  "2011-07-18"
[5,] "5"  "2011-07-20"

> B
      [,1] [,2]         [,3] [,4]
 [1,] "1"  "2011-07-12" "3"  "21"
 [2,] "2"  "2011-07-20" "4"  "20"
 [3,] "2"  "2011-07-18" "2"  "20"
 [4,] "3"  "2011-07-15" "10" "21"
 [5,] "3"  "2011-07-13" "8"  "22"
 [6,] "3"  "2011-07-12" "7"  "19"
 [7,] "4"  "2011-07-12" "9"  "19"
 [8,] "4"  "2011-07-10" "7"  "21"
 [9,] "5"  "2011-07-20" "8"  "21"
```

I want that in table A with a forloop for each row the effective temperature values of tab B are taken if the age is less than 5 days and if the age is greater than or equal to 5 days the temperature is averaged for that station.

I thought that I could do a forlloop and an ifelse, in the meantime I created a column of NA for the temparatura in table A. But I'm stuck on how to write the code. Can you help me? Thank you

```
for(i in 1:nrow(A)){
  ifelse(B$day<5, , )
}
```

What I expect as the output is the new table A like this

```
|col1|col2      |col3|
|1   |2011-07-12|21  |
|2   |2011-07-20|20  |
|3   |2011-07-15|20.5|
|4   |2011-07-12|20  |
|5   |2011-07-20|21  |
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Your description of your expected output isn't very clear to me, so it would be helpful if you could provide the output dataset that you expect based on your desired input.

Comment: Please post the desired output (preferably using `dput(myoutput)`)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `dplyr` to merge, filter and summarise date frames. However it is not quite clear what function should be applied for case when `age < 5` as well as what difference in dates for tables A and B. For this example I put `min` function for case when `age >= 5`.

For future it is better not to use matrices, when dealing with measurements having variables with different types, i.e. table columns are of different types, but `data.frame`s or `tibbles`. Basically matrices allow to use only one data type for all columns (`character`, `integer` or else) and it is difficult to deal with it in a consistent way.

Please see the code below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
A<- matrix(c(1,"2011-07-15",2,"2011-07-20",3,"2011-07-15",4,"2011-07-18",5,"2011-07-20"),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
B<-matrix(c(1,"2011-07-12",3, 21, 2,"2011-07-20",4, 20,2,"2011-07-18",2, 20,3,"2011-07-15",10, 21,3,"2011-07-13",8, 22,3,"2011-07-12",7, 19,4,"2011-07-12",9, 19,4,"2011-07-10",7, 21,5,"2011-07-20",8, 21),ncol=4,byrow=TRUE)

a <- as_tibble(A, .name_repair = ~ c("ss_id", "date")) %>%
  mutate(ss_id = as.factor(ss_id),
         date = as_date(date))

b <- as_tibble(B, .name_repair = ~ c("ss_id", "date", "age", "temp")) %>%
  mutate(ss_id = as.factor(ss_id),
         date = as_date(date),
         age = as.integer(age),
         temp = as.numeric(temp))

a %>% left_join(b, by = "ss_id") %>%
  group_by(ss_id, date.x) %>%
  summarise(temp = if_else(age > 5, mean(temp), min(temp))) %>%
  unique()
```

Output:

```
`summarise()` has grouped output by 'ss_id', 'date.x'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   ss_id, date.x [5]
  ss_id date.x      temp
  <fct> <date>     <dbl>
1 1     2011-07-15  21  
2 2     2011-07-20  20  
3 3     2011-07-15  20.7
4 4     2011-07-18  20  
5 5     2011-07-20  21
```